Proportion of LiDAR point coverage is required to form a 30-m pixel while calculating pixel metrics
I am calculating pixel metrics (30-meter resolution) at area level with the ALS data using lidR package in R. Since the study area has irregular shape, I could see that pixels were formed in some edges (having higher proportion of lidar data within the pixel area) while pixels were not formed in some other edges with limited lidar data. So, out of curiosity, I wanted to know what proportion of LiDAR point coverage (e.g. 20, 30, 40... % of the pixel area/size) is required to form a pixel while calculating pixel metrics using the pixel_metrics() function from the lidR package in R?

Not sure to understand the question. There is a pixel if there is at least 1 point. For more details, you must clarify your question.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Thank you for the clarification, Jean. I tried with only a few metrics and yes, there is a pixel even if there are only few points. In my case, the error might have occurred because I combined all the metrics available in lidR and lidRmetrics in a single list and tried to produce a single multi-layered raster pixel metrics for different return points.
